# fread() after fwrite() gets 0 bytes

Tags: c, linux, file, fedora

I am set a big buffer for the `FILE*` object(size of `8 * 1024`) and I'm making a write of 4 bytes to it and then I read of the 4, but the read fail.
If I flush the `FILE*` the read succeeds.

```
typedef struct _MyFile {                 /* file descriptor */
    unsigned char fileBuf[8*1024];
    FILE *file;
} MyFile;

int main() {
    MyFile myFile;
    int res;
    char bufWrite[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    char bufRead[4];

    /* Open file for both reading and writing */
    myFile.file = fopen("myfile.txt", "w");

    /* Change the file internal buffer size */
    setvbuf(myFile.file, myFile.fileBuf, _IOFBF, sizeof(myFile.fileBuf));

    /* Write data to the file */
    res = (int)fwrite(buf, 1, 4, myFile.file);
    printf("write: res = %d\n", res);

    /* Seek to the beginning of the file */
    fseek(fp, SEEK_SET, 0);

    /* Read and display data */
    res = (int)fread(buf, 1, 4, myFile.file);
    printf("read: res = %d\n", res);
    fclose(myFile.file);

    return 0;        
}
```

The output is:

```
write: res = 4
read: res = 0
```

If I write more than 8K or use `write()` instead of `fwrite()` the `fread()` works well.

**The thing is I can't use `fflush()`!!!**

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: have you tried to open your file in read/write? `fopen("myfile.txt" , "rw");`

Comment: Can't  you just use unbuffered calls (`open`, `read`, `write`)?

Comment: @Eliand fopen("myfile.txt" , "w+");  should do the trick..

Comment: @KlasLindbäck i need to use the `fopen`, `fwrite` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have opened your file in write-only mode. The handle isn't aware that you want to read on it.

Just open your file in read-write mode:

```
myFile.file = fopen("myfile.txt" , "w+");
```

I have tested it and it successfully reads back the data in the read buffer.

write mode only:

```
write : res = 4
read: res = 0
bufRead: -83 20 82 117
```

read/write mode:

```
write : res = 4
read: res = 4
bufRead: 1 2 3 4
```

Edit: my first attempt use `"rw"` mode which worked but gave strange write return value result:

```
write : res = 0
read: res = 4
bufRead: 1 2 3 4
```